# I can´t find the file vue.config.js in my vue cli app

Tags: vue.js

I want to deploy my vue application, I already build that, but i can´t see the file vue.config.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to create it yourself.

> vue.config.js is an optional config file that will be automatically loaded by @vue/cli-service if it's present in your project root (next to package.json).

Source: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js

Comment: Thanks bro that was so helpful